# how to access a double pointer to a structure from another structure in c

Tags: c, pointers, structure

the error is : request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct mia {
    int a;
}hola;

typedef struct m {
    hola **r;
}bic;

int main() {
    bic y;
    scanf("%d", &(y.r->a));
    printf("%d", (y.r->a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before you address this question, you *may* want to ensure `r` is holding a valid pointer. As it is now, it has not one, but two levels of indeterminate indirection.

Comment: `y->r->a` or `(*y.r)->a` or `(**y.r).a`

Comment: @CongXu, `y->r->a` won't work.  `y` isn't a pointer.

Comment: @gia, your other question that you deleted, you never set `nr_query` to a value but used it as a control to a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a more complex syntax for this should do it:

```
int main()
{
    hola x;
    hola *ptr = &x;
    bic y = { &ptr };

    scanf("%d", &((*y.r)->a));
    printf("%d\n", (*y.r)->a);
    printf("%d\n", ptr->a);
    printf("%d\n", x.a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
100
```

**Output**

```
100
100
100
```

Note you can fetch out the `hola *` pointer:

```
hola *ptr = *y.r;
printf("%d", ptr->a);
```

Comment: and what can i do if i have bic y[10] ? how do i access 'a'? or if 'a' is a pointer how do i do ?

Answer (score 2):

Before you can start accessing data off a pointer, you need to allocate some memory first; otherwise, it's undefined behavior. Your current structure needs two levels of allocation - one for the pointer to `hola`, and another for the `hola` itself. You also need to add another level of dereference, because `->` works on pointers to `struct`s, not on pointer to pointers to `struct`s:

```
bic y;
y.r = malloc(sizeof(hola*));
*y.r = malloc(sizeof(hola));
// You need an extra level of dereference (i.e. an asterisk)
scanf("%d", &((*y.r)->a));
printf("%d", ((*y.r)->a));
// Don't forget to free the memory you allocated,
// in reverse order:
free(*y.r);
free(y.r);
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/yR7kkY).